# Symfony 2 : how to handle a mapped form with multiple submit save buttons

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.3

I wonder in a sf2 form how can I manage a form that has several save buttons (submit type).
My form is mapped on an object and I would like to  only persist the personn fields when the 'savePersonn' button is clicked.

Also, I would like to only persist adress fields when the 'saveAdress' button is clicked .
Finally, I would like to save all the form infos when the 'saveAll' button is clicked.
Does anybody know how to do that ? Currently, in my handler, all informations are persisted. 
The code of my formType :

```
<?php

namespace Foobar\OwnerBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class OwnerType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options) {
        $builder->add('firstName', null);
        $builder->add('lastName', null);
        $builder->add('dateOfBirth', null);
        $builder->add('savePersonn', 'submit');

        $builder->add('address', null);
        $builder->add('country', null);
        $builder->add('saveAdress', 'submit');

        $builder->add('saveAll', 'submit');

    }

        public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver) {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'Foobar\CarBundle\Entity\Owner'
        ));
    }

    public function getName() {
        return 'owner';
    }

}
```

Comment: Might be an idea to edit this to make it really clear it's to do with the saving rather than the clicking!

Answer (score 0):

If what you're after is the "only save some of the entity" part rather than the "how to do different things if different buttons are clicked" part, then an option would be what I hinted at below about comparing the altered Entity with a fresh one from the DB, e.g.

```
$ownerRepo = $this->getRepository('Bundle:Owner');
$changedOwner = $ownerRepo->find($id);

//Handle request etc, $changedOwner gets data from submitted form

if ($form->isValid()) {

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    if ($form->get('saveAll')->isClicked() )
    {
        $em->flush(); //$changedOwner was already managed, just need to save all changes
    }
    elseif ($form->get('saveAdress')->isClicked() )
    {
        //Save just address
        $em->detach($changedOwner); //Don't want everything in this to be persisted
        $freshOwner = $ownerRepo->find($id); //untouched
        $freshOwner->setAddress($changedOwner->getAddress() ); //and other fields
        $em->flush(); //Update $freshOwner
    }
    elseif ($form->get('savePersonn')->isClicked() )
    {
        //Save just person
        //As above, but with person rather than address
    }

    return $this->redirect();
}
```

---

*Old answer on wrong track*

As described in the [Symfony Form Docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#submitting-forms-with-multiple-buttons), in your Controller you can test which button has been clicked like this:

```
if ($form->isValid()) {

    if ($form->get('saveAll')->isClicked() )
    {
        //Save entire entity
    }
    elseif ($form->get('saveAdress')->isClicked() )
    {
        //Save just address
    }
    elseif ($form->get('savePersonn')->isClicked() )
    {
        //Save just person
    }

    return $this->redirect();
}
```

You'll have to decide for yourself how to save only part of the Entity; it may involve retrieving another copy from the DB, comparing it with the one populated from the form, and selectively updating only the relevant fields before persisting.

Comment: Putting logic of application it's not good idea, better service/event listener. In this case try use event listener on FormEvents::SUBMIT event

Comment: @jamek Not sure I agree, I think it's the perfect place to put it!  And not as complex as using events.  Most official Symfony examples are like this.  Nice for the Asker to have options, of course.

Comment: Hi, thanks for yours answers. I already knew the isclicked() method, my problem is how to save only some properties of the underlying object. Currently, all the object properties are persisted.
For example : 
How to just persist 'firstName','lastName', 'dateOfBirth' fields when the dedicated submit 'savePersonn' is clicked without persisting the others informations ?
I want to implement the same thing when 'saveAdress' is clicked.

Comment: @ben.IT Ah, well perhaps it would be useful to see your existing persistence code, then?